# GPO - Software restriction policy

Tags: active-directory, windows-xp, group-policy

I was trying to set up GPO - Software restriction policy, so i created the object on our Domain Controller.

Fast forward the next day, everybody who turned off their systems at night could not login (after inserting password, a blank screen comes up with only the cursor). but those who just hibernated or slept their system didnt experience any problem.

I removed the GPO immediately and asked them to restart, all came back to normal...(except a few people running XP). those on windows 7 and 8 are good to go

Now the thing is...those xp clients exhibit many strange behaviors like
- cannot copy and paste 
- task bar has been hidden
- workstation service not starting
- under application in the event log, Software restriction policy is responsible for many errors and alerts
- etc

i believe the policy is still on those systems, even after trying to clear it.

what can i do to resolve this?

Comment: Some details regarding the settings you had made in that policy might be relevant and useful to add to the question, especially any start up or logon scripts that you'd added to the policy, as scripts are most likely to make permanent changes to the systems that can't be undone by removing said policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run gpupdate as admin if you have not tried that.

Software restriction policies do not apply when Windows is started in Safe Mode. You can run gpupdate in Safe Mode to refresh the software restriction GPO.

Answer (score 1):

Connect remotely with PS command

```
gpupdate /target:computer /force /boot
```

It will force to update GPO on target computer and will reboot if necessary.

Might also work:

```
psexec \\computer gpupdate /force
```

In 2nd example if you use '*' instead of 'computer' it will execute command on all computers in current domain.

Answer (score 0):

If gpupdate does not succeed, you might also try

```
gpupdate /force
```